# How to tell the difference between an HtmlGenericControl that is a DIV and one that is a UL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the code below:

```
foreach (Control c in myControl.Controls)
{
    if(c.GetType().Equals(typeof(HtmlGenericControl)))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

My problem is that both UL and DIV tags are considered HtmlGenericControl.  Is there another condition I could add, so that only DIVs enter the if statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [TagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.tagname%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) property:

```
    foreach (Control c in myControl.Controls)
    {
        if(c.GetType().Equals(typeof(HtmlGenericControl)) &&
           string.Equals((HtmlGenericControl)c).TagName, "div", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```